# Is the inverse limit of quotient the quotient of inverse limits?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, quotient-spaces, limits-colimits, filtrations

I am recently studying inverse limits and I have the following issue :

Le $V$ be a vector space and $W \subset V$ a subspace of $V$.

Assume that $V$ is equipped with a decreasing filtration $(\mathcal{F}^m V)_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$. We consider $\hat{V}$ the completion of $V$ for this filtration : the inverse limit of the inverse system $(V/\mathcal{F}^m V, V/\mathcal{F}^{m+1} V \rightarrow V/\mathcal{F}^m V)$. i.e. $\hat{V}:=\underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim} V/\mathcal{F}^m V$.

The subspace $W$ is naturally equipped with the filtration $\mathcal{F}^m W:= W \cap \mathcal{F}^m V$. Therefore, we define $\hat{W}$ to be the completion of $W$ for this filtration : $\hat{W}:=\underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim} W/ \mathcal{F}^m W$.

Now, let us consider the quotient space $V/W$ and the canonical projection $\pi : V \rightarrow V/W$.

The space $V/W$ is equipped with the filtration $\pi(\mathcal{F}^m V)$. We define $\hat{V/W}$ to be the completion of $V/W$ for this filtration : $\hat{V/W} := \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim} (V/W)/\pi(\mathcal{F}^m V)$.

**Question** : Do we have $\widehat{V/W} \simeq \hat{V}/\hat{W}$ ?

This is equivalent to $\underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim} (V/W) \big/ \pi (\mathcal{F}^m V) = (\underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim} V/\mathcal{F}^m V) \Big/ \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim} W / (W \cap \mathcal{F}^m V)$.

Intuitively, it seems true since the filtrations on $W$ and on $V/W$ are naturally defined by the canonical inclusion and canonical projection respectively. But I do not have a clue whether it is true or false. If true my first thought is to begin by
$$(V/W) \big/ \pi(\mathcal{F}^m V)=(V/W) \big/ (\mathcal{F}^m V/\mathcal{F}^m V \cap W) \simeq (V/\mathcal{F}^m V) \big/ (W/\mathcal{F}^m V \cap W).$$
But I do not know if the last identification is true for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and if it is the case how to introduce the inverse limit ?

If false, is there any counter-example for this ?

Any hint or help would be appreciated !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the language of [homological algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homological_algebra), you're asking if exactness of $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ implies exactness of $0 \to \hat{A} \to \hat{B} \to \hat{C} \to 0$. For modules this is false in general, though the claim might be true for finite dimensional vector spaces. In order to guarantee that an inverse limit commutes with quotients in this way, we need to show that $\lim^1(A_i) = 0$, and the standard way to check this is the [mittag-leffler condition](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0594).

Comment: For a nice introduction to this topic, you might be interested in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B2vbZewjILQ) youtube video by Richard Borcherds. In it he explains the condition, proves it's sufficient, and gives counterexamples in the case of mere abelian groups. Since this is a stability condition, it's reasonable to expect it to be automatically satisfied for finite dimensional vector spaces (which might be your case of interest?) but I'm not an expert and I'm about to go to bed, so I don't want to work it out right now. I might try tomorrow if nobody beats me to it, though!

Comment: In fact, I just rewatched the video I linked, and at the end he confirms what I suspected -- in the case the $A_i$ are [artinian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artinian_module) (which for vector spaces means finite dimensional) then the claim follows. Concretely, as long as $W$ is a finite dimensional subspace of $V$, your claim will be true. In case $W$ is not finite dimensional, then it should be fairly easy to build a counterexample. Again, I'll come back tomorrow and write this up more precisely provided nobody beats me to it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am sorry for havng take so long to reply. If I am not mistaken, we do not have inverse limit of quotient is quotient of inverse limit all the time but a condition exists on limit one that can make it possible. In that case the finite dimension on $W$ is not an "if and only if', right ? Anyway, could you suggest me a book on inverse limits if you know a good one. I found Bourbaki hard to read. Thanks again !